# abstract map and vector in stl

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, vector, abstract-class

If I have three types of maps and vectors:

```
map1<CString, int>
map2<CString, int, std::function1>
map3<some_wrapper_of_CString, int, std::function2>
```

In stl is there an abstract container or a way to write my own abstract container for the sole purpose of doing polymorphism:

abstract_map = map1 or map2 or map3

My class contains map1 which I cannot modify because it will crash other classes that my colleges at work use. I thought by creating an abstract map to wrap map1 I can pass map2 and 3 without other modifications...

I hope it makes sense.....

Comment: You would need to fully spell out the actual types of your maps, as well as the relationships between the keys and values (common base, conversion operators, ...) for us to have a chance of understanding what you are attempting and why you believe polymorphism is the solution.

Comment: You also need to type erase on the functor? That is what `std::function` is already there for. How do the types of the two `std::function` types differ? There signature should be the same.

Comment: @pmr The signature is the same but the class has map1 as member and If I pass map2 trough the constructor it gives me an error saying that they are not matching

Comment: @djWann The obvious solution is to make `map1` a `map< CString, int, std::function<...> >`.

Comment: @pmr Imagine there are over 100 other classes that use that class with map1 as it is and if I change its signature they will crash. That is why I try some king of a workaround...

Comment: @djWann Why would they `crash` (They would stop to compile, true)? What you have is a maintenance problem. You need to solve that in coordination with your team. For us to answer we need to know more: How is that member exposed? How is it set?

Comment: @pmr My bad, they will not compile. I agree that is a maintenance problem, which we don't have the time to solve. Map1 is exposed trough the constructor...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't. What would be the purpose of it when the elements are not convertible to each other?

You can always do:

```
containera c;
containerb c2(c.begin(), c.end());
```

which will convert all elements from one to the other container.

If you actually have containers with the same underlying `value_type` the usual abstraction over the container type are iterators and not abstract containers.

After you have clarified that you only want type-erasure on the functor type:

```
class X {
  // constructor taking the full type
  X(const std::map<CString, int, std::function<bool(CString, int)>& x) : my_map(x) {}

  // constructor taking the default std::less
  X(const std::map<CString, int>& x) : my_map(x.begin(), x.end(), std::less<CString>()) {}

private:
  std::map<CString, int, std::function<bool(CString, int)> my_map;
};
```

Comment: The purpose is to modify a class with as less changes possible to obtain flexible behavior on using different types of maps

Comment: @djWann So the T in the maps is always the same?

Comment: @djWann I added a variation that keeps compatibility with existing clients.

Answer (score 2):

> In stl is there an abstract container or a way to write my own abstract container for the sole purpose of doing polymorphism

In the standard C++ library, there isn't.

Templates and dynamic polymorphism don't mix all that well.

Comment: @djWann: Depends on what you're trying to do exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Not only there are no abstract containers in the STL: you should never inherit from STL containers because they are not intended to behave polymorphically (no virtual destructor, for instance). So you have to look for a different solution.

In this case, you have to favour composition over inheritance. You may write your own abstract map class that contains an `std::map`, such as:

```
template<typename T>
class BaseMap
{
  // Whatever you need here

private:

  std::map<T> internalMap;
}
```

and then inherit from this class as needed:

```
template<typename T>
class Map1 : public BaseMap<T>
{
  // Specialise your class here
}
```

Of course, `BaseMap` should offer the interface you need for your maps, since it does not inherit `std::map` interface. You can write any virtual, pure virtual or non-virtual methods you need here.

Though maybe the first question you have to ask yourself is: do you really need different map classes? And, if so, do you really need them to be polymorphic?

Comment: BaseMap should not have a map instance.  The base interface class should be abstract for the above pattern.

Comment: @Yakk Why not? It depends on exactly what it is that you need on your different map classes. If they all can use the same `std::map`, the right place to put it may well be the base class.

Comment: @Yakk Ah, now I see that he changed his question quite a lot after I wrote my answer.